# Obtener el segundo valor mayor

Tags: mysql

El problema lo tengo resuelto, pero expongo aquí mi solución por si hubiera alguna mejor.
(Lo siguiente es un ejemplo, no voy a poner las tablas reales)
Tengo una tabla con rutas y distancias. Se desea obtener el registro con el segundo valor mayor.
Sea la tabla, Rutas:

```
ruta  km
1     20
2     200
3     3000
4     500
5     400
```

Con un

```
SELECT max(km) FROM rutas
```

obtengo la distancia mayor, en este caso 5000. Ahora anidando consultas, si hago:

```
SELECT max(km) FROM rutas WHERE km < (SELECT max(km) FROM rutas)
```

obtengo la segunda mayor distancia, 500, pero si lo que quiero es obtener todos los campos de ese registro e incluyo el campo *ruta*:

```
SELECT ruta, max(km) FROM rutas WHERE km < (SELECT max(km) FROM rutas)
```

obtengo como ruta el primer valor, en este caso el 1. La forma que he encontrado para obtener todos los campos pasa por:

```
SELECT ruta, km 
FROM rutas
WHERE km < (SELECT max(km) FROM rutas)
ORDER BY km DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Con lo que obtengo lo que buscaba 4,  500.

¿Alguna otra solución?

Comment: Debería ser lo mismo ordenarlo por los kilometros y limitarlo desde el segundo registro y que solo muestre uno: `SELECT ruta, km 
FROM rutas 
ORDER BY km DESC
LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: Para el segundo mayor valor sería así: **`SELECT ruta, km FROM rutas ORDER BY km DESC LIMIT 1,1;`**

Comment: Gracias por recordarme el OFFSET (tengo telarañas en la memoria). Para los que no lo conozcan el comentario de @A.Cedano es la forma abreviada de **SELECT ruta, km FROM rutas ORDER BY km DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;**

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from rutas where km not in (
select max(km) from rutas
)
```

Comment: Además de la solución deberias de haber explicado minimanente esta.

Answer (score 0):

se pueden contar las distintas rutas en una subconsulta:

```
SELECT ruta,km
FROM rutas AS r1
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT km)
FROM rutas AS r2
WHERE r2.km>r1.km)
```